# Why wouldn't Unity accept my duplicated animations?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I'm running into quite a dilemma. I duplicated my animation files since I need to add an Event on one of the animations which originally are set to read only. The animations when dragged directly onto the model work well and I can edit them as I see fit. The issue is when I try to add the duplicated animations into a state in the animator, please see the below video for reference. I can add any other type of animation and they work (even the read only) however the ones I duplicated aren't being accepted.

Anybody can pin point why this issue and how I can overcome it?

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6fhCMRYeBw